# How to perform Wasm host call from a Go guest?

Tags: go, webassembly, fastly, tinygo, fastly-compute

How can one call custom Wasm host functions from a Go guest?

I've looked at a few examples that show loading a self-contained witx/wat/wasm defined function, but haven't found an example for performing a host-defined call. Some examples I've looked at are for wazero and wasmtime-go here:

- [wazero example](https://github.com/tetratelabs/wazero)
- [wasmtime-go example](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/bytecodealliance/wasmtime-go#example-package-Gcd)

It would be ideal to be able to make these WebAssembly host calls using pure Go if possible.

Specifically, I'm trying to implement the host calls from the Fastly Compute@Edge ABI defined by [`compute-at-edge.witx`](https://github.com/fastly/Viceroy/blob/b37b89fc07ecd5845f1103380c5e4fae9cc13b30/lib/compute-at-edge-abi/compute-at-edge.witx) and [`typenames.witx`](https://github.com/fastly/Viceroy/blob/b37b89fc07ecd5845f1103380c5e4fae9cc13b30/lib/compute-at-edge-abi/typenames.witx), but this should be generally applicable to any host defined call / function.